# Strange std::bad_alloc in an already-created vector

Tags: c++, vector, std, bad-alloc

I'm running on a `std::bad_alloc` error. As far as I know and as I've seen researching on StackOverflow this can be caused by a lack of the necessary memory to perform an action or because there's some kind of corrupted datastructure ([as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21463585/strange-stdbad-alloc)).

In my case, I've got a class **A** which contains an attribute `std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int> > tiles`. There's no error when this container is created in this way in `A.h`:

```
class A
{
    public:

        //function prototypes
        std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int> > GetTiles();

    protected:
    private:

        std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int> > tiles; //declaration

};
```

Additionnaly i've writen the prototype of a function `GetTiles` which is in charge of returning `tiles`. This is done in `A.cpp` with the following code:

```
std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int> > A::GetTiles()
{
    return tiles;
}
```

In a precise moment another class **B** intends to get the tiles container using `GetTiles` like this (`B.cpp`):

```
std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int> > aux;
aux=InstanceofA->GetTiles();
```

At that precise moment, after the call to `GetTiles()`, I get the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of std::bad_alloc
```

Therefore, it points out to an error when trying to allocate memory for the `aux` container. 
I've tried to make a bit of printf debugging by placing a `printf()` call in the `GetTiles()` function:

```
std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int> > A::GetTiles()
{
    printf("%i\n",tiles.size);
    return tiles;
}
```

Then, before crashing, the program shows a weird result on the console line: `-1524170727`.
Before all this code there's nothing that might affect the `tiles` container and the other vectors declared in `A.h` behave normally and have 0 size after being created as everyone (as far as I understand) expects. I've also tried to place `tiles.clear()` call in the constructor of class A but it does nothing.

**EDIT:** *I've also tried returning other containers in the `GetTiles()` function and it works. Additionally I've also tried calling the function without assigning it's returned value to any container, only:*

```
InstanceofA->GetTiles()
```

*And it also works, so the problem shouldn't be in the returned copy, but in the assignement of it to the `aux` container. I guess the error turns around the weird size of `tiles`.*

I had never seen that before and I haven't found anything in Google. I'll appreciate any help you could give me. Thanks a lot.
I apologize if there's any presentation mistake, it's only the second time I've posted something on SO.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59963/discussion-on-question-by-user3869641-strange-stdbad-alloc-in-an-already-creat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I've solved the problem following the steps pointed by many of the people who have commented my original post, so I really thank everybody. The problem was in the initialization of the pointer `InstanceofA`